# Strange Cassandra issue

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig

I have Cassandra installed in multi node cluster, logically separated in 2 data centers as,

BC1 - Analytics applications are running on these nodes
BC2 - UI applications are running on these nodes

I have a keyspace created as,

```
 CREATE KEYSPACE ks23 WITH replication = {
  'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',  'BC2': '3'
};
```

When I try to access the table data from above keyspace using pig script which is running on one of the BC1 node, I get this error,

```
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:288)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:1054)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1071)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$700(JobClient.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:983)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:910)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.Job.submit(Job.java:378)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol.JobControl.startReadyJobs(JobControl.java:247)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.mainLoopAction(PigJobControl.java:157)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:134)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:259)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not get input splits
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.getSplits(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:197)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigInputFormat.getSplits(PigInputFormat.java:274)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: failed connecting to all endpoints
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.getSplits(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:193)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: failed connecting to all endpoints
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.getSubSplits(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:311)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.access$200(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:61)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat$SplitCallable.call(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:230)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat$SplitCallable.call(AbstractColumnFamilyInputFormat.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

The same script works fine for other keyspaces which are in both data centers

Comment: Are you using a `LOCAL` query consistency level?

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 not sure how to do that... not able to found any info\command for the same

Comment: I updated the replication to have replica on BC1 as well ( BC2:2 ) and ran the node repair command ...............the above error is gone ..however the number of rows I get is much less than actual rows ( I get 95K rows and table has 510K+ rows )

Comment: this page has info on how to set consistency on cqlsh - http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/consistency_r.html